# Log in to a drupal 7 website with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, drupal

I've been trying to create a laravel login with users from a drupal 7 database. Since drupal 7 has his own encription method for passwords, the ones that come with laravel don't work, hence whenever there's a try to log in it always returns authentication failure.

```
    {

        $request->validate([
            'mail' => 'required|string|email',
            'pass' => 'required|string',
            'remember_me' => 'boolean',
        ]);
        //dd(hash('sha256',$request->pass));
        $credentials = request(['mail', 'pass']);
        if (!Auth::attempt(['mail' =>$request->mail, 'pass' => hash('sha256',$request->pass)])) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }
        $user = $request->user();
        
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');

        $token = $tokenResult->token;

        if ($request->remember_me) {
            $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
        }

        $token->save();

        $user->api_token = $tokenResult->accessToken;

        return response()->json($user);
    }
```

This is my login method in the controller.

I don't have access at all to the drupal project.

I'm open for any idea.

Comment: If you dont have access to the drupal installation (hash salt/secret) you can't check the hash back.

Comment: Seems like it is the default one, already managed to verify a user's password in laravel by copying all the methods in password.inc from drupal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you navigate to `includes/password.inc` in your drupal directory, you will find a function named: user_check_password. This method can help you verify your plain text password against the hashed password.

So, the easiest way would be connecting laravel to the existing drupal database and make use of the password.inc file from drupal.

Comment: I don't hace access to the drupal project because it is not mine ^^'

Comment: This file should be same for any drupal 7 project. You can download the official drupal 7 from their website and get the file.